# Updating on linux

Tags: linux

When I enter the command:

```
apt-get update
```

I get an error message telling me that it cant open the lock file. Can anyone explain why this causes a problem and how I can avoid it in the future?

Comment: did you try `sudo apt-get update` ?

Comment: what does 'sudo' mean?

Comment: If you don't know `sudo`, you'd better start reading from basics. `sudo` is a command that allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or another user, as specified in the *sudoers* file.

Comment: thanks raptor and Adem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cant open the lock file
```

You can 2 reasons of this problem:

1. you run `apt-get update` without administrative privileges. Use sudo or login as root.
2. in your system running another `apt-get`, `aptitude`, `synaptic`, `Software Center` or `Update Manager`. Close it ant try again.